# How do I print a range of lines after a specific pattern into separate files when this pattern appears several times in an input file

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

Sorry for my previous post, I had no idea what I was doing. I am trying to cut out certain ranges of lines in a given input file and print that range to a separate file. This input file looks like:

```
 18
 generated by VMD
  C         1.514895       -3.887949        2.104134
  C         2.371076       -2.780954        1.718424
  C         3.561071       -3.004933        1.087316
  C         4.080424       -4.331872        1.114878
  C         3.289761       -5.434047        1.607808
  C         2.018473       -5.142150        2.078551
  C         3.997237       -6.725186        1.709355
  C         5.235126       -6.905640        1.295296
  C         5.923666       -5.844841        0.553037
  O         6.955216       -5.826197       -0.042920
  O         5.269004       -4.590026        0.590033
  H         4.054002       -2.184680        0.654838
  H         1.389704       -5.910354        2.488783
  H         5.814723       -7.796634        1.451618
  O         1.825325       -1.537706        1.986256
  H         2.319215       -0.796042        1.550394
  H         3.390707       -7.564847        2.136680
  H         0.535358       -3.663175        2.483943
 18
  generated by VMD
  C         1.519866       -3.892621        2.109595
```

I would like to print every 100th frame starting from the first frame into  its own file named `"snapshot0.xyz"` (The first frame is frame 0).

For example, the above input shows two snapshots. I would like to print out lines `1:20` into its own file named `snapshot0.xyz` and then skip 100 (2000 lines) snapshots and print out `snapshot1.xyz (with the 100th snapshot)`. My attempt was in python, but you can choose either `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, or `Python`.

My input file: frames.dat

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/Python
  2 
  3 
  4 
  5 mest = open('frames.dat', 'r')
  6 test = mest.read().strip().split('\n')
  7 
  8 for i in range(len(test)):
  9         if test[i] == '18':
 10                 f = open("out"+`i`+".dat", "w")
 11                 for j in range(19):
 12                         print >> f, test[j]
 13         f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the `csv` module for this input.

```
import csv

def strip_empty_columns(line):
    return filter(lambda s: s.strip() != "", line)

def is_count(line):
    return len(line) == 1 and line[0].strip().isdigit()

def is_float(s):
    try:
        float(s.strip())
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def is_data_line(line):
    return len(line) == 4 and is_float(line[1]) and is_float(line[2]) and is_float(line[3])

with open('frames.dat', 'r') as mest:
    r = csv.reader(mest, delimiter=' ')
    current_count = 0
    frame_nr = 0
    outfile = None

    for line in r:
        line = strip_empty_columns(line)
        if is_count(line):
            if frame_nr % 100 == 0:
                outfile = open("snapshot%d.xyz" % frame_nr, "w+")
            elif outfile:
                outfile.close()
                outfile = None
            frame_nr += 1 # increment the frame counter every time you see this header line like '18'
        elif is_data_line(line):
            if outfile:
                outfile.write("    ".join(line) + "\n")
```

The opening post mentions to write every 100th frame to an output file named `snapshot0.xyz`. I assume the `0` should be a counter, ot you would continously overwrite the file. I updated the code with a `frame_nr` counter and a few lines which open/close an output file depending on the frame_nr and write data if an output file is open.

Comment: I am sorry, but did you check this script? I can not get it to print out any files. I am adding print `i` + ".dat" at the bottom to do so.

Comment: Is your data tab-seperated? --> use `csv.reader(delimiter='\t')`. In case of multiple spaces the reader is not as user friendly (will give a bunch of empty columns for each additional space).

Comment: With the current code, all that is printing is "output file: i" and nothing else. My data is not tab separated, but I see you add white space delimiter. It seems its not reading in the file. I will edit my question to show what the data looks like exactly.

Comment: The code sample is just parsing the input, not writing any output files. Add your output handler at the bottom (inside the `is_data_line` clause). You can use the `current_count` and `r.line_num` state varables (it wasn;t clear to me on which one the output file number should be based).

Comment: I'm sorry, but as I am new I have no idea what you are eluding to. Here is what I added. It prints correctly, but I do not know how to print each snapshot of 20 lines to a different file.

Comment: wow! thank you so much Freek! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for being patient with a newbie like myself. My original code was not even close. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and csplit):

```
sed -rn '/^18/{x;/x{100}/z;s/^/x/;x};G;/\nx$/P' file | csplit -f snapshot -b '%d.xyz' -z - '/^18/' '{*}'
```

Filter every 100th frame using sed and pass that file to csplit to create the individual files.